Power supply gives at most 20 millivolts
I have a power supply KIKUSUI MODEL PAB 250-0.25A (photo below).
The voltage source used to work correctly, but my roommates have used it for a while and now whenever I connect it to a load and toggle the "output" to ON, it gives at most some 20 millivolts. I connected it only to a 220R resistor and an LED (which is forward-oriented) but for any load it just drops to mV whenever the "output" is on.
Do you have any idea about what is happening, and why the power supply may be behaving this way? Maybe any testing techniques to troubleshoot the problem?


What’s the current limit set to?

@winny the max current allowed for the supply is 0.25A I think. I always put the Current potentiometer on max and just regulate the voltage. But I've tried adjusting the current and the behavior remains the same (but for even less mV). When I put it on C.C and [A] option, the max current it drives is 0.033A. No more than that

Probably broken. Take it apart and measure all rail voltages. If there, probably blown output pass transistor.

The  PAB 250-0.25A has an input and an output fuse. Check the output fuse, it's a normal 1/4" x 1-1/4" type rated at 300mA.
If it is open, replace it with the same type and rating.


It was it! Thank you very much!
